# from_json returns null in Apache Spark Kafka readStream

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I'm trying to read kafka topic and display the data on console using pySpark. I've defined the from_json schema and trying to match and display it. However, the **df returns nulls**.

**Original object in kafka topic and schema are blow.**

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
  "etag": "jUow4VqgbKTDD9d1QI8TBQdM0po",
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "SRkYji_KdZvK3LDoACVdkHcm-Og",
      "id": "E4R_WJBqaaQ",
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2022-03-30T13:51:05Z",
        "channelId": "UCw9DyZg3_F0bIks2jrEgQAA",
        "title": "Brother Job #sadiqahmed",
        "description": "",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/E4R_WJBqaaQ/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/E4R_WJBqaaQ/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/E4R_WJBqaaQ/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          },
          "standard": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/E4R_WJBqaaQ/sddefault.jpg",
            "width": 640,
            "height": 480
          },
          "maxres": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/E4R_WJBqaaQ/maxresdefault.jpg",
            "width": 1280,
            "height": 720
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Sadiq Ahmed",
        "categoryId": "22",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "localized": {
          "title": "Brother Job #sadiqahmed",
          "description": ""
        }
      },
      "statistics": {
        "viewCount": "5155911",
        "likeCount": "559596",
        "favoriteCount": "0",
        "commentCount": "844"
      }
    }
  ],
  "nextPageToken": "CAEQAA",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 200,
    "resultsPerPage": 1
  }
}
```

**json Schema definition**

```
mySchema = StructType([
    StructField("items",ArrayType(StructType([
                        StructField("id", StringType, True),
                        StructField("snippet", StructType([
                                StructField("channelId", StringType, True),
                                StructField("channelTitle", StringType, True),
                                StructField("categoryId", IntegerType, True),
                                StructField("publishedAt", TimestampType, True),
                                StructField("title", StringType, True)]), 
                            True),
                        StructField("statistics", StructType([
                                StructField("commentCount", IntegerType, True),
                                StructField("favoriteCount", IntegerType, True),
                                StructField("likeCount", IntegerType, True),
                                StructField("viewCount", IntegerType, True)]),
                            True)]), True), True)                    
])
```

**Reading Kafka Topic and transforming to from_json**

```
df = spark.read.format("kafka")\
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaServer)\
    .option("subscribePattern", topic_name_read)\
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")\
    .load()\
    .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")\
    .select(F.from_json(F.col("value").cast("string"), mySchema).alias("data"))\
    .select("data.*")
```

**The current output.**

```
+-----+
|items|
+-----+
|null |
+-----+
```

What's wrong in my schema definition. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most commonly, it is null because the fields do not match. I believe you are required to define every single field, and so you should try adding `kind`,  `etag`, and anything else you've missed.

You could also use `get_json_object` instead of defining a Schema if you really only need certain fields from a String.

Comment: Thank you, I've defined the entire JSON schema, that works for me!